# how to label equations in this way?

Tags: labels

Suppose Alice has an equation labelled by (3).
After several pages, she wants to label a new equation by (3)',
to indicate that the new equation (3)' is an analog of (3).
How does she type in Latex to get the label (3)'?

Comment: "Go ask Alice...when she's ten feet tall." (sorry, I couldn't resist the classic song lyric).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - We seriously risk betraying our age by providing such references. :-) I recently managed to lose my audience with a reference to "One Word: Plastics"...

Comment: @Mico And here I discover a little more about “Plastics”. But remember that it's not only the age, also the country we are from influences in our understanding ;)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I cannot believe that this is the first time that I notice the existence of the lyric... Thanks for the happy accidence!

Comment: @Manuel - I'm afraid the query to which you had posted one one-word comment and I had posted "Plastics" got deleted before I had a chance to provide some follow-up. Anyway, do a search for "graduate plastics" on youtube and enjoy the scene from the movie "The Graduate", Dustin Hoffman's break-out performance that made him a huge star. :-)

Comment: the more usual formulation is "(3')", with the prime *inside* the parens.  i think this is shown in the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsmath`), ir, if not there, in some of the other `amsmath` documentation, linked from http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.

Answer (score 7):

I just came up with a solution to my own problem. Suppose Alice uses `\label{eq3}` to label (3). She can label a new equation as (3)' in the following way:

```
\begin{equation}\tag*{(\ref{eq3})'}\label{eq3'}
THE NEW EQUATION.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: If you use the `amsmath` package then you can reference equations with `\eqref{}`, which puts parentheses around the equation number automatically.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for leading me to the command! To use `(\ref{...})` was one of my primordial habits. Now `\eqref` is ubiquitous. :)